# Split Mp3 in same sized chunks without saving/export them

Tags: python, pydub

Hello I want to split an `AudioSegment` into chunks that are all 10 seconds long. I tried it like this:

```
for n in range(int(duration/10)):
    start = n*1000*10
    end = (n*10+10)*1000
    audio_segment = audio[start:end]
```

The problem is now that i want to access these chunks. But when I enter the `audio_segment` variable into the function i am using the following error pops up:
`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'AudioSegment'`.

This error obviously tells me that it only accepts a `bytes-like object`. I can turn the `AudioSegment` into a `bytes-like object` by exporting it into a mp3 and then open it up again as `rb` but this solution takes very long and is in my opinion not good because I really do not need these segments to be saved.

Can anyone help me access the `AudioSegment` as a `bytes-like object` without saving it?

Comment: you could try to use `io.BytesIO` to create file-like object in memory.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe `AudioSegment` has som function to get it as bytes-like data?

Comment: in [source code of AudioSegment](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/audio_segment.py) I found function `.raw_data()` and maybe this is your solution.